# Deleted the path in user variables by mistake

Tags: windows, path, environment-variables

I  was setting path for MinGW in environmental variable , double clicked the "path" variable in User variables and rename it as "Path" and set the values to "C:\MinGW\bin;C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\bin;", still by typing g++ it showing 'g++' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.  Now my previous "path" and its values are replaced by "Path". All my Program Files paths are removed . Maybe I am unable to explain the situation properly...hope u help.

Comment: why don't you change the name back to path

Comment: Ehm, if you replace *c++* tag with *windows* you'll have more chances for help

Comment: g++ is also not  recognizable that's why i put C++ even after  setting path. I messed up with the EV

Comment: @SuryanshSingh change back to path , the variable values are empty now

Comment: Did you use the windows advanced settings (i.e. change the OS-wide settings) or a specific path variable in your IDE (as e.g. eclipse provides to extend the system wide settings)? In the former case you are out of luck, the former path most likely is lost (you might try to recover from a system restore point, though).

Comment: If you used a console and ´SET´ command then you can just open a new console and adjust the path as needed as follows: `SET PATH=%PATH%;your\additional\path` (or prepend, if more appropriate).

Comment: If  you can , restore windows to some other point in past

Comment: @Aconcagua i have tried the SET command but still i don't remember all my default paths and additional paths in it. I think i lost them completely . Is there any way to find to recover or know the default  or previous paths

Comment: `SET` doesn't change variables persistently. So just close the console and open a new one, then you should see your old path restored (try a raw `SET` with out equal sign or anything else appended to see a list of all variables set). In the new console you then can adjust the path as shown in my previous comment.

Comment: "Maybe I am unable to explain the situation properly" Yes, that is true. :-) Did you use the `regedit` program or something like it to change the Windows registry? It is not clear what you mean by "double clicked the "path" variable in User variables".